# como saber las dimensiones de un tercer array sin ponerlas manuales

Tags: java

Para sumar dos matrices bidimensionales

```
int[][]uno = new int[4][3]
int[][]dos = new int[4][3]
```

Con valores x,  y una guardarla en una tercera llamada  resultado

```
int[][]resultado = new int[?][?]
```

Como calculo las dimensiones del los indices i y j del  array resultado para que
tengan la cantidad exacta?

Comment: En una suma de matrices, la matriz resultante es del mismo tamaño, que las matrices sumandos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Espero no haberlo complicado mucho

Pongo en el supuesto que no buscas sumar los valores de los array, sino añadir los valores de un array al otro. O sea, si el primer array tiene 4 filas y el segundo otras 4, el resultado será de 8 filas.

Con las columnas haríamos lo mismo, teniendo en cuenta que las columnas se multiplicarían, o sea, un array con 4 filas, que tenga 4 columnas por cada fila, tendrá 16 columnas en total.

Si por el contrario, deseas sumar los array, como bien dice @Exodia, el array resultado tendría las mismas filas y columnas que los array que forman la suma.

Lo hice todo en métodos diferentes para que cada uno haga su trabajo de forma independiente

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //declaramos los dos arrays bidimensionales
    int[][]uno = new int[4][3];
    int[][]dos = new int[4][3];
    
    //llamamos a los métodos para contar las filas y columnas de cada array, y recibimos un array con el resultado
    int[] unoCon = contarUno(uno);
    int[] dosCon = contarDos(dos);

    //con el resultado anterior, llamamos ahora al método que declarará el tercer array de forma automatizada que recibiremos del mismo      
    int[][] resultado = formarResultado(unoCon, dosCon);

    //para probar que todo funcione, llamamos al método para contar filas y columnas del nuevo array bidimensional que enviaremos por parámetro y recibiremos otro array con el resultado    
    int[] resultadoCon = contarResultado(resultado);

    //mostramos en pantalla el número de filas y columnas del primer array        
    System.out.println("El array uno tiene: \n" 
            + unoCon[0] + " filas \n"
            + unoCon[1] + " columnas");
    System.out.println("=========================");

    //mostramos en pantalla el número de filas y columnas del segundo array        
    System.out.println("El array dos tiene: \n" 
            + dosCon[0] + " filas \n"
            + dosCon[1] + " columnas");
    System.out.println("=========================");

    //mostramos en pantalla el número de filas y columnas del tercer array formado con la suma de los dos anteriores        
    System.out.println("El array resultado tiene: \n" 
            + resultadoCon[0] + " filas \n"
            + resultadoCon[1] + " columnas");
    System.out.println("=========================");

}
//método para contar las filas y columnas del primer array que lo recibe por parámetro    
public static int[] contarUno(int[][] uno){
    //creamos un array de enteros que guardará el número de filas y columnas
    int[] unoCon = new int[2];
    //creamos los contadores de filas y columnas
    int contadorF = 0, contadorC = 0;
    //creamos un bucle para contar las filas
    for (int row1 = 0; row1 < uno.length; row1++){
        //por cada iteración sumamos una fila
        contadorF++;
        //almacenamos el número de filas en la posición 0 del array del método
        unoCon[0] = contadorF;
        //creamos otro bucle que contará las columnas
        for (int colum1 = 0; colum1 < uno[row1].length; colum1++){
            //por cada iteración sumamos una columnas
            contadorC++;
            //almacenamos el número de columnas en la posición 1 del array del método
            unoCon[1] = contadorC;
        }
    }
    //retornamos el array del método con el número de filas y columnas
    return unoCon;
}
public static int[] contarDos(int[][] dos){
    int[] dosCon = new int[2];
    int contadorF = 0, contadorC = 0;
    for (int row2 = 0; row2 < dos.length; row2++){
        contadorF++;
        dosCon[0] = contadorF;
        for (int colum2 = 0; colum2 < dos[row2].length; colum2++){
            contadorC++;
            dosCon[1] = contadorC;
        }
    }
    return dosCon;
}
public static int[] contarResultado(int[][] resultado){
    int[] resultadoCon = new int[2];
    int contadorF = 0, contadorC = 0;
    for (int row3 = 0; row3 < resultado.length; row3++){
        contadorF++;
        resultadoCon[0] = contadorF;
        for (int colum3 = 0; colum3 < resultado[row3].length; colum3++){
            contadorC++;
            resultadoCon[1] = contadorC;
        }
    }
    return resultadoCon;
}
//método que declara el nuevo array bidimensional con la suma de los dos array que recibe como parámetro
public static int[][] formarResultado(int[] uno, int[] dos){
    //en variables recogemos los valores de las filas y columnas de cada array
    int filas1 = uno[0];
    int columnas1 = uno[1];
    int filas2 = dos[0];
    int columnas2 = dos[1];
    //sumamos las filas de ambos array
    int filas = filas1 + filas2;
    //sumamos las columnas de ambos array
    int columnas = columnas1 + columnas2;
    //declaramos el array con las cifras obtenidas
    int[][] resultado = new int[filas][columnas];
    //devolvemos el nuevo array
    return resultado;
}
```